# ARM template deployment fails

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-rm-template

I created a cluster through the Azure portal and I'd like to make some updates to it through the ARM templates. I have made the necessary edits to the template (specified placement constraints) and I'm using [this script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-samples-powershell-deploy) to deploy to the remote cluster. I'm getting an error message 'The value of deployment parameter 'abc_xyz' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference'. The value for that parameter is defined in my ARM template but it is null in the parameters.json:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "abc_xyz" : {
         "defaultValue" : "abc_xyz_name",
         "type": "String"
},  
}
```

Parameters.json:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {
      "abc_xyz" : {
      "value": null
},
```

For this example, assume that the parameter "abc_xyz" refers to a public address of an azure resource (storage account, load balancer, etc). Am I missing something here? Why is my deployment failing?

Comment: Do you try remove ` "defaultValue" : "abc_xyz_name",` in your ARM template,  if your parameters,json value is `null`, you don't need use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parameter.json, your `abc_xyz` value is `null`, it means that you need provide value when your deploy the template. In the main template, you don't need use `defaultValue`. You could modify your template as below:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "abc_xyz" : {

         "type": "String"
},  
}
```

Comment: Could I instead replace the defaultValue from template.json into the values field in parameters,json?

Comment: I got past this issue by commenting out the parameters.json file (the values were null anyway) and submitting a new deployment. The placement constraints I wanted to set on the node types were also set successfully.